# Как вывести только не совпадающие данные в pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Сравниваю две таблицы excel:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(self.filename, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[3,4,5,20])
df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[3,4,5,20])
difference = df1[df1 != df2]
```

результат сравнения вывожу в третью таблицу:

```
df1.to_excel(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Результат.xlsx")
```

но в неё попадают все строки. Как их убрать, оставив лишь те, которые не совпали с первой таблицей?

[Исходные данные](https://transfiles.ru/2zbey)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU дополнил кодом свой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если наименования столбцов в обоих фреймах совпадают, то можно попробовать сделать так:

```
diff = df1.loc[df1.ne(df2).any(axis=1)]
```

Пример решения для данных по ссылке:

```
In [105]: df2.loc[df1.ne(df2).any(axis=1)]
Out[105]:
   №     Товар  Цена
0  0  Карандаш    70
3  3  Резинка     50
```

Comment: А если наименования столбцов не совпадают? Есть такая вероятность.

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, тогда нужны воспроизводимые примеры данных в вопросе)

Comment: Код в вопрос добавлен

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, меня интересует воспроизводимые примеры данных, а не код )

Comment: Понял) добавил ссылку на файл в вопрос там excel файл на первых трёх листах у таблиц одинаковые названия колонок на следующих трёх разные на третей и шестой странице результат сравнения каким он должен быть.